# Issue with SCSS media query on iPhone 15 and Xiaomi Mi9

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I have website on `React` and I want to properly align buttons in the container using `SCSS`. I target multiple devices with different screen resolutions. It works well but I have issue on `iPhone 15` and `Xiaomi Mi9` phones. When checking the `screen.width` for both devices it returns as `393px`.

**iPhone 15:**

```
@media screen and (width: $device-width-393) and (height: $device-height-852) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (min-resolution: 3dppx) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 1.9rem;
    gap: 1.9rem;
  }
```

**Xiaomi Mi9:**

```
  @media screen and (width: $device-width-393) and (height: $device-height-851) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.75) and (min-resolution: 2.75dppx) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 2.7rem;
    gap: 2.7rem;
  }
```

**Code:**

```
.cities-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  grid-gap: 0.9rem;
  gap: 0.9rem;

  @media screen and (width: $device-width-393) and (height: $device-height-852) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (min-resolution: 3dppx) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 1.9rem;
    gap: 1.9rem;
  }

  @media screen and (width: $device-width-393) and (height: $device-height-851) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.75) and (min-resolution: 2.75dppx) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 2.7rem;
    gap: 2.7rem;
  }

  @media screen and (width: $device-width-834) and (max-height: $device-height-1194) and (orientation: portrait) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    gap: 2rem;
  }

  @media screen and (width: $device-820) and (height: $tablet-1106) and (orientation: portrait) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 1.8rem;
    gap: 1.8rem;
  }

  @media screen and (width: $tablet-ipad-small) and (height: $desktop) and (orientation: portrait) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 1.6rem;
    gap: 1.6rem;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-435) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 3.1rem;
    gap: 3.1rem;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-415) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 2.6rem;
    gap: 2.6rem;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-413) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 3.2rem;
    gap: 3.2rem;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-390) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 2.5rem;
    gap: 2.5rem;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-380) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 2.1rem;
    gap: 2.1rem;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-375) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 1.3rem;
    gap: 1.3rem;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-365) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 1.5rem;
    gap: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

It fails to target `Xiaomi Mi9` phone and applies the style for `screen and (max-width: 413px)` rule.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this style issue by checking `max-width: $smartphone-395` (395px) for `Xiaomi Mi9` and removig the check for height: `(height: $device-height-851)` (851px) for `iPhone 15` phone.

**Code:**

**Xiaomi Mi9:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: $smartphone-395) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 2.7rem;
    gap: 2.7rem;
 }
```

**iPhone 15:**

```
@media screen and (width: $device-width-393) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (min-resolution: 3dppx) {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-gap: 1.9rem;
    gap: 1.9rem;
  }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

It looks great on both phones. Now, the issue is resolved. Thank you.